# What causes exception in string.concat

Tags: .net, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

Here are few classes:

```
public class MyItem : ParamOut
{
    public string Code
    {
        get { return _quoteCode; }
    }

    public InnerItem[] Skus
    {
        get { return _skus; }
    }

    public PriceSummary Price
    {
        get { return _price; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Concat("Code=", Code, "; SKUs=[", Skus != null ? "{" + string.Join("},{", Array.ConvertAll(Skus, item => item.ToString())) + "}" : "", "]"
            , "; Price={", Price.ToString(), "}", base.ToString()
            );
    }

    ...
}

public abstract class ParamOut
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Here is calling functionality:

```
{
    MyItem item = new MyItem{ ErrorMessage = "Bla-bla-bla" };
    string text = item.ToString();
}
```

I am getting NullReference exception inside of 'ToString()' method (each property of item variable is null).

Question:

Q1. what overload of string.Concat will be called in this case? I have 9 parameters, so I guess one of the following:

```
public static string Concat(params Object[] args)
```

or

```
public static string Concat(params string[] values)
```

But which of them?

Q2. Why exception is generated? Shouldn't 'null' be converted into something like 'null' or "" (empty string)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you post the full traceback and maybe some sample execution that causes it to throw?  I'm guessing that you're hitting the null exception on `item.ToString` inside your ternary operator or on `Price.ToString()` or `base.ToString()`, and it's not `Concat` itself that's barfing on a null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

q1: you are only passing in strings so it will use the string[] version

q2: in addition to what matt said, even if Concat allowed null values, you'd still get the exception from where you call Price.ToString() since Price is null

Answer (score 1):

1. I guess, that the overload with 'Object[]' is called (as parameters of different types are used) (please correct me if I wrong).
2. Price.ToString() caused an error if Price is null. And .ToString() is not required here at all

Answer (score 1):

1. The most appropriate overload - if all parameters are string then the string overload will be called. Since they are not, the `Object` overload will be called.
2. The `Price` might be null or one of the `SKU` items or even `Code`, so calling `ToString` on any of these (passing objects to `Concat` will call `ToString`) will throw the NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't 'null' be converted into
>   something like 'null' or "" (empty
>   string)?

What should it be converted to? Some people would like the empty string, others would like "null", etc. Microsoft decided to not answer that, as there are many things that would be valid answers here. So MS took the safer route and just throws an exception.

Comment: Just to be clear, it's the call of .ToString() on a null reference that's causing the exception, not passing null to `Concat`.

Comment: That is true. But still `Concat` is not checking if a parameter is null then handling it as a special case, so in a sense my answer is still valid. MS decided to not handle concatenation of nulls.

Comment: Within the `Concat(params string[] values)` method, individual strings *are* treated as Empty if they are null.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat.aspx  "An Empty string is used in place of any null object in the array"

Answer (score 0):

First off, I suspect your `NullReferenceException` is because you're calling `ToString` on a null object.

However, trying to concat `null` will also give you that Exception.

In this case, you might prefer to use `string.Format`.

```
return string.Format("Code={0}; SKUs=[{1}]; Price={2}{3}", 
    Code ?? "null",
    SKUs != null ? 
        string.Join(",", SKUs.Select(s => "{" + s.ToString() ?? "null" + "}")) :
        string.Empty,
    (Price ?? "null").ToString() ?? "null",
    base.ToString() ?? "null");
```

You can see the use of the null-coalescing operator (??) wherever you might be dealing with a null value.

```
x.ToString() ?? "null"
```

is logically equivalent to

```
x.ToString() == null ? "null" : x.ToString()
```

I've gone a bit over the top with how many null checks there are, but it looks like there are a lot of potential gotchas in the code you have there. :)

Comment: `x.ToString() ?? "null"` will cast a `NullReferenceException` if x is null.

Comment: Yes, you can see I handled this for "Price", but not for the list of SKUs.

Comment: It'd also be helpful to just ensure that your own ToString methods never return `null`, so that you can just check the base object (ie, (Price ?? "null").ToString()) itself instead of every ToString call as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you said it yourself:

> (each property of item variable is null)

You should probably check that the array of `InnerItem`s (from the `Skus` property) contains any `null` elements.

They could probably be avoided with a simple `Where`-clause, or similar.

And to answer your questions:

- Q1: The `string[]` overload will be called.
- Q2: `Concat` will treat `null` as an empty string.